# Is it safe to "search" creating db records in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search, activerecord

I need to build a search form including some fields like "city, price range, key word and date". I saw this video which is recommending to create a "searches" table. Every time any user made a search, it creates a table row in the db, and show the results depending on the submitted fields.

Seems easy to build but is it safe? I mean, if this is used in the practical world, I think we also have to use "I'm not robot" from Google.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QRE7KxIvUb4&t=29s

Any idea is welcome.

Comment: Why do you want/need to do it this way?

Comment: If you are going to record interactions, you will have to add some kind of limiter, like for instance, as you suggest, Google recaptcha (application layer). It would take a bot minutes to flood your db....

Comment: The only reason I can think of not using GET requests for advanced search is the limit of the URL length, which is practically unlikely to hit. Even if you use POST requests, that still doesn't mean you have to insert anything into database. If you want to analyze user behavior, log files are often good enough.

Comment: I was just wondering this is a very basic thing, yes a bot can blow up the db in minutes but Railscast is one of the best reference for learning rails. How can they recommend this way? Anyway, I'm just looking for a simple way to advance search and analyse user search data at the same time.

Comment: I would say that this has more to do with whether it is one of your requirements / user experience requirements. It is a nice feature but I don't see many apps doing it. I would also consider an alternative form for storing past queries such as using cookies.